# C# UWP - How to get an object's drag image?

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

How can I get a copy of the drag image for an item I'm dragging in my application?

The [DragStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragstarting) event contains a [DragStartingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DragStartingEventArgs) object that includes a [DragUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dragui) object whose description is, "*The visual representation of the data being dragged.*"  Ideally, I'd like to do something like this within the DragStarting event:

```
    private void OnDragStarting( UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args )
    {
        // Create a new bitmap image object
        var dragImage = new BitmapImage();

        // Assign the drag image to the new bitmap image object
        dragImage = args.DragUI. ????
    }
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the drag image from the DragUI object. DragUI contains only "Set*" methods, and no "Get*" methods.

Is there a way to get the drag image as the drag operation begins?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? During DragStarting no image has been set yet. It's up the app to set it at that point. Hence there is only a Set method, no Get. Please clarify the scenario.

Comment: The drag source is a third-party control whose drag image is created and displayed as expected. I have no prior access to its drag image.

The drag target is a diagramming control that requires you to populate a "container" with the drag image in order for the image to appear when dragging over the diagram "canvas". If you don't populate this container, the drag image doesn't appear when over the diagram.

I'm simply trying to get the source control's drag image to pass along to the diagram control's "container" so the diagram will display the drag image while dragging over its "canvas".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync()` to receive the items you dragged into your applications.

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Image_drop_drag_over_ui" Drop="image_drop"/>
```

//C# code

```
public async void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
     {
        List<StorageFile> received_images = new List<StorageFile>();
        var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
        var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
        received_images.Add(storageFile);
     }
}
private void Image_drop_drag_over_ui(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
     e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Drop receipt";
     e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = true; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not providing a data package, I have no prior knowledge of the image that appears in the drag operation, and the Drop event is too late to retrieve the drag image -- I need to retrieve the drag image as soon after the drag starts as possible. (See my detailed explanation of the scenario in my comment above.)